# Question about DateTime.Now in C#

Tags: c#

```
DateTime startTime = System.DateTime.Now;

//do the search
Graph_SearchBFS BFS = new Graph_SearchBFS(Graph, sourceCell, targetCell);

DateTime endTime = System.DateTime.Now;
```

How come startTime equals endTime? What does that mean? By the way my goal is to measure how much time it takes for the graph search.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It means that the system clock granularity is too large to measure this sort of thing accurately - in other words, calling the constructor happens pretty quickly.

However, you can use a class which is more appropriate for precision timing - or at least, it can take advantage of a high-precision clock if one is available: [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
Graph_SearchBFS BFS = new Graph_SearchBFS(Graph, sourceCell, targetCell);
sw.Stop();
```

Now you can look at the [`sw.Elapsed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed.aspx) property to see how long it took.

Of course, it's entirely possible that it will *still* be too fast to measure. Typically for benchmarking you do something enough that you can time over the course of many seconds, rather than a single operation.

As an aside, is your `Graph_SearchBFS` *constructor* actually doing the work? If so, that's a bit of a design smell as well. Typically I'd expect code more like this:

```
Graph_SearchBFS BFS = new Graph_SearchBFS(Graph);
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
BFS.FindCell(sourceCell, targetCell);
sw.Stop();
```

or something similar. Then you can loop lots of times over the "finding" part:

```
Graph_SearchBFS BFS = new Graph_SearchBFS(Graph);
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
{
    BFS.FindCell(sourceCell, targetCell);
}
sw.Stop();
```

Comment: @pokoko222: Oh dear - that's not a terribly good sign for the book :( (Nor is the class name, by the way.)

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your method ran faster than the resolution of the clock.

Use the `StopWatch` class instead; it's more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) to measure execution speed

```
  Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
  sw.Start();

  Graph_SearchBFS BFS = new Graph_SearchBFS(Graph, sourceCell, targetCell);

  sw.Stop();
  Debug.WriteLine("Time to query: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the method is very fast.  Have you looked at the milliseconds or ticks?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.millisecond.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx